# How to use res.render in any PUG template not only the one rendered?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to use students collection in few other templates, except "studentsinclass".

```
router.get('/students/:id',passportConfig.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
Student.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
        res.render('studentsinclass', {
            students:docs

        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error in retrieving students: '+ err);
    }
});
```

});

I had been studying about

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.locals.student = req.student;
next();
});
```

But I can't understand the concept?
My Schema looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
fullName: {
    type: String
},
classroom: {
            name: {
                    type: String
                    },
            id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                    ref: "classroom",
                }
            },

});

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

With this code, I can use,

```
extends layout

block content
ul
each student in students
    li= student.fullName
```

..and is working, but I need to use it in other pages as well. 
Thank you and I apologize if sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the question. You want to render your students data from the database on other pages besides 'studentsinclass' ?

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to my question. Yes, I need to use the same iteration is the homepage for example, but that's not working since I render just "studentsinclass". I need to use the iteration in a few different pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on your homepage you first need to get the right page from your router:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

});
```

Now inside of here you render the data that will be displayed on your homepage, so just use the same render function again:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Student.find((err, docs) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('home', {
        students: docs
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Error in retrieving students: ' + err);
    }
  });
});
```

Now, if you route to `/` or `yourdomain.tld/`, it will render the homepage with the students data. To receive the data on your homepage make use of `#{students}!`

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't solve the problem, since docs is not defined in home.js.

Comment: If you wrap the render function inside your Students.find() function...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require?

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const students = ["irshad", "alex", "lushiku", "pop"];
  res.locals.students = students;
  next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { message: "Hello world" });
});

app.get("/firstpage", function(req, res) {
  res.render("firstpage", { message: "First Page" });
});

app.get("/secondpage", function(req, res) {
  res.render("secondpage", { message: "Second Page" });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**students.pug**

```
ul
    each val in students
        li= val
```

**index.pug**

```
h1= message
include students.pug
```

**firstpage.pug**

```
h1= message
include students.pug
```

**secondpage.pug**

```
h1= message
include students.pug
```